# How use order by condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, conditional-statements, records

Is it possible to sort the data on a condition?

For example, figuratively, `.order( "expiration_date <?", Time.current, :desc )`

Comment: That doesn't make any sense, you can't order just some of the records. What are you trying to do exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The ORDER BY keyword is used to sort the result-set by one or more columns.
The ORDER BY keyword sorts the records in ascending order by default. To sort the records in a descending order, you can use the DESC keyword.**

you can sort by using something like :-

```
sorted = @records.sort_by &:created_at
```

or try [**where**](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/where) by first getting the resultset and then sorting it:-

```
@records.where( "expiration_date <?", Time.current).order( :created_at, :desc )
```

Moreover you can paginate easily;-

```
@records.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 15)#.order(" created_at ASC")
```

Comment: But If I want get list with expiration_date >=?", Time.current (initialy) and expiration_date <?", Time.current (then) ? So, and how use will_piginate for it?

Comment: Hi @Stas...i have updated my answer for pagination...give it a try and let me know :)